# Where can I find the Google Talk Android client source code?

Tags: android, android-source, google-talk

I found an app called IM in Android's trunk on git, but that doesn't look like the Google Talk app that comes installed on Android phones.

Does anyone know if that source code is even published?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is closed source. But you can take the apk and disassemble it using [baksmali](http://code.google.com/p/smali/).

Answer (score 5):

It's closed source.